# InnoDB transaction interleaving and atomicity

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, innodb

Consider a hypothetical logging system that groups the incoming logs into `LogIndex` periodically. At a time, there is only one `Active` index which can receive new logs.
There is a periodic job which transitions `LogIndex` from `Active` -> `Closed` state, if no new logs arrive within last 1hr.

The DB schema is as follows:

```
1. LogIndex (Id, State [Active|Closed])

2. Log (Id, LogIndexId, LogLine, LogTimestamp)
```

There could be a scenario where 2 DB transactions run in parallel:

**Transaction 1 : To insert a new log line**

```sql
Query1. Select Id from LogIndex where State='Active' LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
Query2. Insert into Log values(Id, LongIndex.Id, LogLine, LogTimestamp);
```

**Transaction 2 : Periodic checker to determine if the index needs to be closed**

```sql
Query1. Select Id from LogIndex where State='Active' LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
Query2. Select LogTimestamp from Log where LogIndexId='<someLogId>' order by LogTimestamp desc Limit 1;

<If the LogTimestamp is more than 1 hour old, then>

Query3. Update LogIndex set State='Closed' where Id='<someLogId>'
```

I have few questions starting with very basic ones:

**Q1:** When the `Select` is running with `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, would the queries inside the transactions still execute in interleaved manner?

**Q2:** Assuming interleave execution happens:
If we want to avoid using exclusive locks like `Select...LOCK FOR UPDATE`, then how can we serialize these transactions to avoid the inconsistent state due to following sequence:

t1: `Transaction1 - Query1` -> Selects the LogIndex in `Active` state. There is only 1 LogIndex in `Active` state at a time.

t2: `Transaction2 - Query1` -> Selects the LogIndex in `Active` state

t3: `Transaction2 - Query2` -> Lists all the logs from the LogIndex

t4: `Transaction2 - Query3` -> Updates LogIndex as `Closed`

t5: `Transaction1 - Query2` -> Inserts Log record for LogIndex.Id just set as `Closed`

*Or another possible scenario:*

t1: `Transaction1 - Query1` -> Selects the LogIndex in `Active` state. There is only 1 LogIndex in `Active` state at a time.

t2: `Transaction2 - Query1` -> Selects the LogIndex in `Active` state

t3: `Transaction2 - Query2` -> Lists all the logs from the LogIndex where last log was more than 1 hour old

t4: `Transaction1 - Query1` -> Inserts Log record for LogIndex.Id which is in `Active` state

t5: `Transaction2 - Query3` -> Updates LogIndex as `Closed`, even though there is a new log inserted at t4.

DB in question is MySQL InnoDB with default isolation level set to REPEATABLE READ.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a list of statements that get the job done.  Ignore multiple connections, etc.
2. Add `BEGIN`, `FOR UPDATEs`, and `COMMIT`.

Those two steps may suffice.

More discussion.

Can the code be changed to do many rows at once?  If so, that will provide considerably more scalability, and much less likelihood of conflicts.

How long does a "transaction" take?  Hopefully less than a second.

The usual pattern is

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;   -- any rows that you don't way changed
...
UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE -- whatever is needed, in whatever tables
COMMIT;
```

Of the `SELECT(s)` fetch more than one row (say 10), have an `ORDER BY` so that they are always in the same order.  (This avoids a certain class of deadlock.)

I don't understand "Selects the LogIndex in Active state" -- is that one row?  all 'Active' rows?  a LIMIT?

Note:  If the "closing" task is fast enough, you may need only one of them.

See also the "ping-pong" technique where data is being inserted into one table while the other table is being emptied.  Then they swap:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Imply use the default Isolation Level.

"Lists all the logs from the LogIndex where last log was more than 1 hour old" -- How many can there be?  A dozen = ok.  A million = potentially too slow to have in a transaction.

`Update LogIndex set State='Closed' WHERE id = ...` You may be able to fold the preceding `SELECT` in by using a `JOIN` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks for your post @Rick. >I don't understand "Selects the LogIndex in Active state" -- is that one row? all 'Active' rows? a LIMIT? -> Regarding this there could just be one LogIndex in `Active` state at any time.

Comment: > Update LogIndex set State='Closed' WHERE id = ... You may be able to fold the preceding SELECT in by using a JOIN instead of WHERE.     There is some more business logic that needs to perfomed on the log lines before deciding if it needs to closed. For simplicity I have avoided that in the question. But there could be more than few hundred logs which need to parsed as a part of transaction.

Comment: I suppose SELECT..FOR UPDATE is more expensive lock as compared to SLECT..FOR SHARE. So if the transaction also processes list of Logs, the transaction could be expensive.  Specially when there is a high inflow of Logs those need to be processed as well.

Comment: Batching is likely to be very beneficial for a "high inflow".